# Javascript Pull/Push Single/Multiple

Tags: javascript, rxjs

i'm currently learning **RxJS**.

inside the doc, i find this array. 
[image]

i try to search "pull and push javascript" on google but i don't even know how to call those entity/concept.
i can't figure it out what that means ? 
i assume Single / Multiple is about the value returned but
my question is about the difference between Pull and Push ?

Can you bring me the light ?

Comment: The image comes from this page: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html In the introduction they clarify what RxJS is by saying: "Think of RxJS as Lodash for events". That really helps.

Comment: Damn, i don't get it. i should be able to understand what pull / push is with the sentence "Think of RxJS as Lodash for event" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pull: returning a value.

- Single: functions return a single value on use.
- Multiple: Iterators return multiple values and are more like a stream of data

Push: sending an event with a value to its listeners

- Single: promises trigger its own event listeners with a value once
- Multiple: Observables(what is added in this docs page) trigger any subscribed event listeners with new data any time it is called

I don’t actually use RXJS but if you’re unsure about how these 4 things work read Kyle Simpsons [You Dont Know JS book on async](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/async%20%26%20performance).

I hope I brought you the light.

Comment: Thx, for the book. I'll give a look at it

Comment: Good explanation .